# Press and hold key programmatically java

Tags: java, multithreading

Alright, I've searched now for a whole day, but no result. Maybe someone can help it.

I'm trying to generate a key "press and hold" situation in my java program, programmatically. Let me explain the situation:

I listen constantly for an event. Consider 2 events 'A' and 'B'. If event A occurs, I want to press and hold down the keyboard key (X), and if event 'B' occurs, I want to release the key (X). Now the main thing is, this all has to be a side process, so even if A occurs, I can listen for event B.

I've tried making a separate thread, making an infinite loop inside it, pressing the key using 'Robot' in java, but it turned out to be the most inefficient way of achieving this, as it consumes more than 60% of CPU. I've tried achieving this with a state changed, but don't seem to find a way to restrict the key press, to change only when I want it to.

I would appreciate a solution without any infinite loop, if possible, as I am already using 1 to listen for event occurrences. (Suggestions are welcome)

Here is my code for the thread:

```
public class KeyPress implements Runnable {
public String command;

public void run() {
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();

        while (true) {
            //System.out.println(command);
            if (command.equals("up")) {
                r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
                r.delay(20);
                r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
            } else if (command.equals("finish")) {
                break;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

The instance of thread is created as usual, in my main class. 
Also, if someone can explain this - when I remove or comment out the

```
System.out.println(command);
```

statement (as you see in the code), This thread stops working. If I add this, it works. Although this problem is secondary, as it still is a non-feasible solution.

Comment: Define *"stops working"*.

Comment: If you send the KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED event without the KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED event, does that not achieve the desired effect?  What's missing from that solution?

Comment: @m0skit0 stops working here means it stops doing anything. It does not respond to events, (i.e. command change)

Comment: @PaulHicks It does not work either. Where it is expected to keep the up key pressed, it only works once, and stops. All event changes after that are not responded to either (command changes)

Comment: Maybe Robot isn't up to the task then.  If you need to keep a key pressed, and `Robot#keyPress()` only pushes the key (and doesn't hold it), maybe you need to send the events manually?

Comment: @PaulHicks I agree. But sending events manually is the same thing as writing an infinite loop to generate events, until the actual event of releasing the key is generated

Comment: It doesn't look like it.  Sending a since KEY_PRESSED event is the same as holding the key down.  Calling keyPress() is the same as pushing the button and letting go.  Putting that in a loop is like tapping the key.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, keyPress() is working like we are tapping the key, however one would expect it to hold down the key, since we have a separate method named keyRelease(). I am not quite sure how it is intended to work, but tapping is all it does when I use it. KEY_PRESSED event sends the event when the hardware key is pressed, regardless of you release it instantly or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after a long and tiring attempt to solve this problem, I think I might have a solution.

Firstly, I create a thread everytime event 'A' occurs, although its the same as before. When event 'B' occurs, I interrupt the thread, which makes it to exit. Since these events 'A' and 'B' occur alternatively, this works for the CPU usage problem.

Another optimization, and possibly the answer to the problem of having to write print() statement, was I made the variable `command` as `volatile`. As explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable), the compiler optimization was most likely the problem I was facing.

Here is the code after these changes:

```
public class KeyPress implements Runnable {
public volatile String command;

public void run() {
    try {
        Robot r = new Robot();
        while (command.equals("up") && !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
            r.delay(20);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
}
```

I hope this helps someone, and someone can provide suggestions on how to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

[Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) maybe a good solution.

Do not loop in the thread. Use notify and listener mode like this:

Listen to the command:

```
class RobotObserver implements Observer{
    private Robot  r = new Robot();
    @Override
    public void update(Observable o, Object arg) {
        String command=arg.toString();
        if (command.equals("up")) {
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
            r.delay(20);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_UP);
        } else if (command.equals("finish")) {
            System.out.println(command);
        }
    }
}
```

Notify listener:

```
Observable observable = new Observable();
observable.addObserver(new RobotObserver());
observable.notifyObservers("up");
observable.notifyObservers("finish");
```

**PS:** class `Observer` and `Observable` are both in package `java.util`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This solution is just a way to generate notifying events, and does not solve the problem of holding down the key.

Comment: You can hold the key down at else if condition.

Comment: How to do that? All I got till now is, you have to keep calling r.keyPress() repeatedly in order to make it hold down a key = infinite loop